# Upgrading Laravel 4 password reset controller to Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have successfully upgraded most of my Laravel 4 application to Laravel 5, but the password reset portion is giving me a hard time. When I try to send the password reset email, I get this error:

> ErrorException in PasswordBrokerManager.php line 137: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker' does not have a method 'remind'

This is the code it doesn't like:

```
/**
 * Handle a POST request to remind a user of their password.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function postRemind()
{
    switch ($response = Password::remind(Input::only('email')))
    {
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
            return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));

        case Password::REMINDER_SENT:
            return view('notifications.email');
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this might not be working?

**EDIT**

Changed `Password::remind` to `Password::sendResetLink`, and now I am getting this error:

> FatalErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 126: Class '\App\User' not found

It is correct, I do not have a class in the \App namespace since I moved it into \App\Models. How can I let it know that it should be looking for \App\Models\User instead?

Comment: There is no `remind` in the `password` class located in `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker`. Please show us that file.

Comment: @Matt OK, I can do that, but it is in the vendor folder so it should be stock ;)

Comment: @Matt http://laravel.io/bin/6L3ev

Comment: @Matt I think I figured out that error, any idea what's going on with this new error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the user model's fully qualified class name in the `config/auth.php` file, in the `providers` configuration values:

```
...
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    ...
]
...
```

Aside from that, Laravel 5 already has a [`App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/PasswordController.php) class that imports the [`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php) trait which handles all that forgot password functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the default password controller but since I had a lot of custom stuff going on in the laravel 4 password controller I figured I would just convert it over the L5 ;)

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but figured it doesn't hurt to post that info as well :).